# MySQL selection in one column

Tags: mysql, select

We have a following table:

```
+-------+----------+----------+
| id    | time1    | time2    |
+-------+----------+----------+
| 18413 | 00:00:00 | 00:00:24 |
| 18415 | 00:00:01 | 00:00:25 |
| 18557 | 00:00:02 | 00:01:31 |
| 18432 | 00:00:03 | 00:00:30 |
| 18428 | 00:00:04 | 00:00:28 |
+-------+----------+----------+
```

How can we make this one using mysql selection:

```
+-------+----------+
| time    | result |
+-------+----------+
| 00:00:00 | time1 |
| 00:00:01 | time1 |
| 00:00:02 | time1 |
| 00:00:03 | time1 |
| 00:00:04 | time1 |
| 00:00:24 | time2 |
+-------+----------+
```

We mix time1 and time2 in one column and group them by type and in the result column we mark them if they were time1 or time2.

Comment: Why doesn't the example resultset contain `00:00:25`, `00:01:31`, `00:00:30` or `00:00:28`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT  time1 as time,'time 1' as result
FROM TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT time2,'time 2' as result
FROM TableName
```

See an example in [**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9843/1).

**EDIT:**

If you want to order them as per the `time` column, just add a `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT  time1 as time,'time 1' as result
FROM TableName
UNION ALL
SELECT time2,'time 2' as result
FROM TableName
ORDER BY T.time
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Now i have to make cursor for all this stuff which will count +1 if we have time 1 and count -1 if we have time 2 ordered by time and what i need to know is the possible maximum which will cursor reach :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with the fields you specified, and first insert into it values (SELECT time1 FROM first_tabl), "time1", and then similarily insert for "time2" column.